# Why adjust spacing according to font size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am designing the margin spaces for elements on a web page.

As I read the document for Bootstrap V4.0, I found that the spacing are adjusted according to the value $spacer, and $spacer itself is 1 rem by default. I am just curious about why is it the case? Shouldn't spacing adjusted base on the display resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to have your dimensions based on a root size, which is what `rem` does. If the root em is 10 pixels then 2rem = 20 pixels. If you ever felt everything need to be bumped up a tish in size, then you would only have to change the root em size to 12 (or something) pixels and then anything with 2rem would now be 24 pixels. This saves you from having to find and replace all the instances where your padding/margin etc. was based on 10 pixels and you used a fixed value like `padding: 10px`.

---

While this is a great cascading effect when sizing elements, fonts etc. Don't feel you need to use relative units like `rem` and `em` all the time. There will be times when you want/need `15px` no matter what.